# Is there any way to change encoding of externalozed strings option in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I have most of my strings in the project already localized and if I use eclipse function to externalize strings, it will make property file like this:

```
BulkUploadModule_13=Vyberte slo\u017Eku na serveru
```

which is completely uneditable! Is there any way to tell eclipse to NOT do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from legacy uses of properties files...

You may have noticed that the `Properties` class, *prior to Java 1.6*, only had a method to read properties via an `InputStream`... Which is not "made" to read characters.

It used a builtin encoding, and that encoding was ISO 8859-1! And my guess is that U+017E (this is [this character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/017e/index.htm) by the way) is not encodable by ISO...

Since 1.6 however you can write to a properties file using a `Writer` and read using a `Reader`, and therefore choose your encoding (hint: UTF-8! UTF-8! UTF-8!). But no idea whether Eclipse can do that via its GUI. Programmatically, it's certainly possible, however.

Comment: The Eclipse NLS code insists on the ISO 8859-1 encoding

Comment: I would have to manually copy the text into message file and then make a constant. This is absurd amount of work for every single string.

Comment: @Enerccio The 'Source > Externalize Strings' tool can do that for you

Comment: @greg-449 That is the problem, it will but it will create file with lines like the one I posted in the question, which are completely uneditable by anyone!

Comment: And why don't you just manipulate that text programmatically instead of relying on Eclipse? You _do_ realize that this is what my answer basically says, right?

Comment: @fge so I should write a script that would parse my java source files and extract it that way?

Comment: Well, that's the first time you actually say anything about where those strings were. If they are in Java files which you can compile that is all the more reason to do it programmatically. Or you didn't explain 5% of the story.

Comment: Well I thought the fact that I want to use externalize strings would suffice. Basically I have string literars in my code (messages, names etc) and want to extract them to a file. But problem with externalize strings is, that it will save the text as that ISO nonsense, which is noneditable.

Comment: Well then write them in one shot as UTF-8 in "plain Jane Java"; and arrange so that you read them back the same way. This will just work.

Comment: Decided to write my own Control which supports utf-8 and externalize strings normally into ISO, then replaced all non ISO characters back into normal utf-8.

Comment: Why write ISO? Just write UTF-8 directly